# Calculate Sales and Stock in R

Tags: r, database, dplyr

Im working with a Sales/Stocks database. Original tablet had a problem, only show the last `STOCK` status by `Date`, `SKY`, `COMPANY` and `STORE`, like this example.

| Date | SKU | COMPANY | STORE | SALES | STOCK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-05 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-01-06 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 0 | 5 |

I need create Stock's history in the original table, starting from the last date to the first existing date, like this table:

| Date | SKU | COMPANY | STORE | SALES | STOCK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 9 |
| 2022-01-03 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 8 |
| 2022-01-04 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 7 |
| 2022-01-05 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 1 | 6 |
| 2022-01-06 | ABC | WALMART | DOWNTOWN | 0 | 5 |

Basically I must add to the stocks of the previous day, the amount of sales of the day and I dont know how to do this with `dplyr::group_by()`.

Thanks in advance.

Example file [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlzPczTzEA7aiNsO-Ay2FMXxD58eew?e=Ptotdy)

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but to do this with the original dataset you provided (`have`), you can get the desired dataset you provided (`want`) using:

```
have <- read.table(text = "Date SKU COMPANY STORE   SALES   STOCK
                 2022-01-01 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN    1   0
                 2022-01-02 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN    1   0
                 2022-01-03 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN    1   0
                 2022-01-04 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN    1   0
                 2022-01-05 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN    1   0
                 2022-01-06 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN    0   5",
                 header = TRUE)

want <- have %>% mutate(new_value = rev(max(STOCK)+cumsum(rev(SALES))))
```

Output:

```
#   Date       SKU COMPANY    STORE SALES STOCK new_value
# 1 2022-01-01 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN     1     0        10
# 2 2022-01-02 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN     1     0         9
# 3 2022-01-03 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN     1     0         8
# 4 2022-01-04 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN     1     0         7
# 5 2022-01-05 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN     1     0         6
# 6 2022-01-06 ABC WALMART DOWNTOWN     0     5         5
```

Note I didnt rewrite over the original column, but instead created a new one just for purposes of this example

You can then use `group_by()` to do this in datasets among groups.

Please note that many users don't click on external links or download external datasets (including me); if this doesn't solve your issue please update the data provided in your question to be more representative of the real data and I'll be happy to edit my answer!